# How to find bitwise or on multiple records?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation,There is a user and multiple roles assigned to him.So i have multiple records for same userid.for a particular column like AllProgramights ,i may have values
`10101,01101`. I should get value as `11101`.

Is there any way?

sample data:

UserID   ProgramAccessRights
01        10101
01        01101

result should be like this

01       11101

i think we need to do something like bitwise or ,but i dont know how to do this

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: What is the criteria to get this `11101`

Comment: @ Abe Miessler i have given sample data and hope this will clear the question.

Comment: @Anoop  ,charcher by character bitwise operation gives the final result